# Inappropriate blocking method call, but Suspend function 'withContext' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-context

In my Service, I need to call on `onStartCommand` some methods that require `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` instead `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)` like:

- url = URL(pokemon.linkImage)
- url.openConnection().getInputStream()
- fOut= FileOutputStream(file)
- fOut.flush()
- fOut.close()

But `Suspend function 'withContext' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function`. So if `onStartCommand` can't be a suspend function because it has override and `withContext` can't be called by CoroutineScope because `Inappropriate blocking method call` of methods

```
val url = URL(pokemon.linkImage)
val iS = url.openConnection().getInputStream()
```

How can I resolve this problem?

My **onStartCommand()**:

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

    //create the directory on internal storage that will contains all pokemon images
    val path = applicationContext.filesDir.absolutePath
    val dirName = "/pokeimg"
    val dir = File(path, dirName)
    if(!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdir()
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        //get the list of pokemon when they are loaded from repository
        val listOfPokemon =
            PersistenceSingletonRepository.getInstance(applicationContext).getListOfPokemon()
        //download all the image for each pokemon in the list, but only if the image is
        //not present in the directory
        for(pokemon in listOfPokemon) {
            val imageName = "${pokemon.name}.png"
            val file = File("${dir.absolutePath}/$imageName")
            //check if image not exists on internal storage and if is not an official-artwork
            //images that aren't official-artwork has less quality so don't resize
            if(!file.exists()) {
                //download img
                val url = URL(pokemon.linkImage)
                val iS = url.openConnection().getInputStream()
                val opts = BitmapFactory.Options()
                if (!Utils.isBadImage(pokemon.linkImage)) {
                    //request a smaller image
                    opts.inSampleSize = 2
                }
                val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iS, null, opts)
                val fOut= FileOutputStream(file)

                bitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut)
                fOut.flush()
                fOut.close()
            }

        }
        stopSelf()
    }
    return START_NOT_STICKY
}
```

Comment: "that require `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` instead `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)`" -- what does this mean? You need a `CoroutineScope` from somewhere. What `CoroutineScope` do you intend to use?

Comment: URL(pokemon.linkImage) get 'Inappropriate blocking method call' warning when I use it in CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO). So I need to use withContext(Dispatchers.IO) instead CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)

Comment: @CommonsWare Open connection to URL needs a thread that is not the main thread. So I used the CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO) but I get the warning 'Inappropriate blocking method call'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can safely ignore that warning, it's known to have many false positives. You launched the coroutine in the IO dispatcher, which is designed for blocking calls.

On the other hand, launching anything with an ad-hoc `CoroutineScope` that has no parent and no lifecycle binding, is usually the wrong thing to do. You should respect the Service lifecycle and cancel your coroutine in `onDestroy`. See for example [here](https://kenkyee.medium.com/android-kotlin-coroutine-best-practices-bc033fed62e7).

Comment: That warning is coming from the IDE inspections, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it's not a compiler error.