# Inappropriate blocking message call even using Dispatchers.IO

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to load a bitmap from a contentResolver inside a suspend function, and Android Studio is giving me a warning that it's an "Inappropriate blocking method call". I thought that I understood why this was, so I placed it inside a "withContext(Dispatchers.IO)" block, but I still see the warning.

```
private suspend fun loadBitmap(uri: Uri): Bitmap? {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            val bmOptions = BitmapFactory.Options()
            requireContext().contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)?.use { inputStream ->
                // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, bmOptions)
            }

        } catch (exp: Exception) {
            null
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your situation is the same one as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69066847/inappropriate-blocking-method-call-but-suspend-function-withcontext-should-be

Basically, you did it right but for some reason the compiler logic that raises this error is buggy. Your code looks like the most straightforward approach and I'm really suprised you get that false positive.